# Can Google Red Security warning reflect on emails delivery?

Tags: google-search-console, email

Website was hacked and had deceptive content in it and Google added security red warning on it. Since the website had this warning, my emails are not working. I don't receive them as the emails contain website link which was hacked and had google warning. When I try to remove that link from the email and re-send, I receive it immediately.

So I've cleaned website files, created Google search console and requested a review to Google from there.

In 2 days, I received a message in console:

> Google has received and processed your security review request.
>   Google systems indicate that {website address} no longer contains
>   links to harmful sites or downloads. The warnings visible to users are
>   being removed from your site.

Yes, the warning was removed but I still don't receive emails.

I've checked both the IP of server and domain in https://www.spamhaus.org, https://mxtoolbox.com/ and some other email blacklist tools and all say that it is not blacklisted.

Maybe when google adds that red security warning, it also reflects on emails delivery? How can I solve this issue so that my emails will work?

Comment: Is, at any point, GMail involved? If so, then I would say Yes. Otherwise, this is an outstanding question. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes gmail is involved @closetnoc

Comment: I do not know much of anything about G-Mail except that they do keep their own blacklist and there does not seem to be much information on it. It would make sense to me to be blacklisted because of the website link, however, now that you are cleared, who can say how long it would take to clear-up being blacklisted by G-Mail? Hopefully not long! This is definitely an interesting question. We have learned something new! Cheers!!

Comment: I see. So the only thing I can do is to wait-and-see. Thanks @closetnoc

Answer (score 1):

You mention that GMail is involved in the email chain. Google maintains its own blacklist compiled from its own internal data sources as well as third party blacklists.

While not specifically documented anywhere (so far as I know) I have found that if a site is marked down with the red security warning the domain and the constituent IP's are flagged by Google's blacklist. If this is the case then there would usually be a response email from Google stating that the email could not be delivered due to the blacklist but not always. Only thing you can do here is wait and hopefully the record is removed from Google's blacklist a bit after it has been removed from the site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already 1 month 15days had passed but emails issue still persists! @Chris Rutherfurd

Comment: In that case if you are sure your ip and domain don't show up on any blacklists tthrough mxtoolbox.com then you can go to https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery which is a webform for Google where you can report the delivery problem. They will be able to look into it and perhaps either you have missed a blacklist entry, or Google has not yet automatically pulled your record out of their own blacklist.

Comment: Ok I will submit it! Before I found this form but didn't think that this could help but will try now surely. Thanks a lot! @Chris Rutherfurd